# create process and attach C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I have a doubt, when I create a new process `iexplore`, and this process opens one single page, I would like know if the page loads correctly. How can I learn if the page load fails ?. Is there any way to catch an error from `iexplore` process?

I have this demo code, but doesn't work correctly

```
string navegador = "C:\\program files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = navegador;
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(navegador);
p.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "google.com";

p.Start();

Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();


p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
                        prsProjectTypes_OutputDataReceived);
p.BeginOutputReadLine();

errorMessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's obvious that English is not your native language, and that's fine, but your question is almost impossible to understand.

Comment: Trying to rephrase the question, please see if it is any better and still reflects your task. Can you say what is the exact error condition that you want to monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working WPF, you should look at the Web Browser control rather than launching a separate process. This will give you access to the [LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event which seems to be what you're looking for.